# I want to translate my HTML text

Tags: javascript, json, html, translate

I wanted to translate texts in my web site I used this code, I know that I'm close to get the right solution.

Somewhere in my HTML code:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu.about">A PREPOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li ><a class="lang">FR</a></li>
        <li ><a class="lang">EN</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and  this is my JavaScript code :

```
var dictionary, set_lang;


// Object literal behaving as multi-dictionary
dictionary = {
    "fr": {
        "menu" : {
            "about": "à propos",
            "services": "services"
        }
    },
    "en": {
        "menu" : {
            "about": "about",
            "services": "services"
        }
    }
};

// Function for swapping dictionaries
set_lang = function (dictionary) {
    $("[data-translate]").text(function () {
        var key = $(this).data("translate");
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(dictionary[key]);
            return dictionary[key];
        }
    });
};

// Swap languages when menu changes
$(".lang").click(function() {
    var language = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    console.log(language);
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
        set_lang(dictionary[language]);
    }
});

// Set initial language to French
set_lang(dictionary.fr);

});
```

In this part :

```
<li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu.about">A PREPOS</a></li>
```

The Text 'A  PREPOS' can't be translated, but when I change It to:

```
<li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu">A PREPOS</a></li>
```

I can see my object 'menu' using `console.log`

Comment: Your `dictionary` structure is strange - and once it gets bigger you'll (believe me) find it hard to maintain.

Comment: Its not fixed, $(this).text().toLowerCase(); does teh same job as $(this).html().toLowerCase();

Comment: If I use <li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu">A PREPOS</a></li>

the console shows when I click FR and EN: 
Object {about: "à propos", services: "services"}
Object {about: "about", services: "services"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your call to `dictionary.hasOwnProperty("menu.about")` returns false.

You need to traverse the tree of objects so you're getting the property like this:

```
dictionary["menu"]["about"]
```

I've put together a simple recursive example on how you can traverse the tree of objects.

```js
// Object literal behaving as multi-dictionary
dictionary = {
  "fr": {
    "menu": {
      "about": "à propos",
      "services": "services"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "menu": {
      "about": "about",
      "services": "services"
    }
  }
};

// Function for swapping dictionaries
set_lang = function(dictionary) {
  $("[data-translate]").text(function() {
    var key = $(this).data("translate");
    return parseSubObject(dictionary, key);
  });
};

function parseSubObject(obj, str) {
  var props = str.split(".");
  
  var thisProp = props.shift();
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(thisProp)) {
    if (props.length == 0) {
      return obj[thisProp];
    } else {
      return parseSubObject(obj[thisProp], props.join('.'));
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// Swap languages when menu changes
$(".lang").click(function() {
  var language = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
    set_lang(dictionary[language]);
  }
});

// Set initial language to French
set_lang(dictionary.fr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu.about">A PREPOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a class="lang">FR</a></li>
  <li><a class="lang">EN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dictionary` logic is totally off. `services` i.e: will always be services and there's not good reason to use an additional `menu` layer. Redundant and repetitive should be avoided.
Rather use **properties** like:

```js
var dictionary = { // props in alphabetical order ok? promise?
  // prop   : {fr, en}
  about     : {fr:"à propos", en:"about"},
  services  : {fr:"services", en:"servicesssss"}
};

function translate( lan ) {

  $("[data-translate]").text(function(){

    var data = this.dataset.translate.split("|");
    var prop = data[0];  // the dictionary property name
    var style = data[1]; // "uppercase", "lowercase", "capitalize"

    if(!prop in dictionary) return console.error("No "+ prop +" in dictionary");

    var trans =  dictionary[prop][lan]; // The translated word

    // Do we need to apply styles?
    if(style==="capitalize"){
       trans = trans.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + trans.slice(1);
    } else if(style==="uppercase"){
       trans = trans.toUpperCase();
    } else if( style==="lowercase"){
       trans = trans.toLowerCase();
    }

    return trans;
  });
}

// Swap languages when menu changes
$("[data-lang]").click(function() {
  translate( this.dataset.lang );
});

// Set initial language to French
translate("fr");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#about" data-translate="about|uppercase">A PREPOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services" data-translate="services|uppercase">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a data-lang="fr">FR</a></li>   <!-- data-* attributes can be helpful -->
  <li><a data-lang="en">EN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that `dictionary.fr.menu.about` (*à propos*) is the same as `dictionary.fr['menu.about']` (*undefined*).

Note the data structure of each section of `dictionary.fr.menu.about`:

1. `dictionary`: Object
2. `dictionary.fr`:  Object
3. `dictionary.fr.menu`:  Object
4. `dictionary.fr.menu.about`: String

In order to get to the String, you need to walk the objects, which you can do with this code:

```
set_lang = function(dictionary) {
  $("[data-translate]").text(function() {
    var key = $(this).data("translate").split('.'),
        val = dictionary[key.shift()];

    while(key.length) {
      val = val[key.shift()];
    }
    return val;
  });
};
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var dictionary, set_lang;


// Object literal behaving as multi-dictionary
dictionary = {
  "fr": {
    "menu": {
      "about": "à propos",
      "services": "services"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "menu": {
      "about": "about",
      "services": "services"
    }
  }
};

// Function for swapping dictionaries
set_lang = function(dictionary) {
  $("[data-translate]").text(function() {
    var key = $(this).data("translate").split('.'),
        val = dictionary[key.shift()];
    
    while(key.length) {
      val = val[key.shift()];
    }
    return val;
  });
};


// Swap languages when menu changes
$(".lang").click(function() {
  var language = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
  console.log(language);
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
    set_lang(dictionary[language]);
  }
});

// Set initial language to French
set_lang(dictionary.fr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#about" data-translate="menu.about">A PREPOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a class="lang">FR</a></li>
  <li><a class="lang">EN</a></li>
</ul>
```